# Как установить новый набор инструментов платформы в Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, windows-xp

Хочу чтобы моя программа, написанная на С++ работала на ОС Windows XP.
Для этого необходим набор инструментов платформы Visual Studio 2017 (v141_xp).
Возникает вопрос, как установить этот набор без переустановки VS? В списке предложенных у меня только Visual Studio 2017 (v141).
И как это повлияет на работу программы? Все будет работать также только теперь и на XP?

Comment: В инсталляторе выбираете соответствующую оснастку и все. А как это повлияет на работу программы - хз, программу вы же не показали.

Comment: @VTT, спасибо за ответ. Как я понял, то обязательно нужно переустанавливать VS для этого. Верно?

Comment: Нет... Оснастки можно добавлять и удалять без переустановки.

Comment: @VTT, большое спасибо - разобрался. Касательно программы могу сказать, что она работает с файловыми БД.